# Quiero condicionar un option con un evento onClick , React

Tags: reactjs, onclick, options

Quiero usar el evento onClick en el option tag de mi select, use ternarios pero no me funciona , lo que quiero es que al seleccionar la opción "otros" aparezca el input para llenar información adicional mediante texto. para ello estoy empleando react.

```
<div>
  <select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="other">otros</option>
  </select>
  
  { value==='other' ? (<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Llenar otra información" />
  </div>):null}
 </div>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías expandir un poco mas sobre lo que has intentado por favor?

Comment: Pues aqui noto mas una necesidad de JavaScript que algo relacionado a React

Comment: Claro , tengo un select con varias opciones , lo que quiero es que solo al seleccionar el ultimo option "otros" , me aparezca un div con un input para llenar texto adicional, intente incrustarle un onClick dentro del option , pero no funciona. tambien intente usar  el ternario value === 'other' para que esconda el div y solo aparezca cuando elijo esa option , pero sigue sin darme resultado.

Comment: el codigo que puse es solo referencial , ya que el proyecto lo estoy trabajando en react.

Comment: ok,  de algún lado sale `value` es una variable?, *quiero publicar una solución pero trato de obtener la mayor cantidad de detalles de lo que llevas, solo por eso son las preguntas*, para que podamos cumplir con las reglas de [ask]

Comment: No , solo estoy interpretando que el "value" que asigne a los option se puede usar para interpretar información a la hora de emplear ternarios.

Answer (score 2):

Para que te funcione el ternario tendrías que establecer "value" como una variable, ya que en otro caso no puedes analizarla en un condicional

Una opción es usar los hooks de React para establecer un estado con esa variable haciendo el input select de tipo "controlado", que viene a decir que en todo momento estás controlando el valor de ese selector dentro de una variable

Por ejemplo para crear esa variable usas el hook y controlas el selector de este modo:

```
...
const [value, setValue] = React.useState()

return (
    <select
      value={value}
      onChange={e => setValue(e.currentTarget.value)}
    >
      ...
    </select>
  );
```

Comment: En general debemos esperar a que el OP muestre algún avance concreto sobre la duda que expone

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte @Pablo Cianes, me ha servido de maravilla